# Qual è il senso di "costare" in questo testo?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Colti infine nei lacci della Giustizia gli attuali giudicabili. 
>          Ritenuti in cosifatto modo i fatti in genere. 
>          Il Presidente ha proposto la seguente
>                         
>              
>                         
>   QUISTIONE
>          **Costa** che i prevenuti D. Ignazio Cozzo, Salvatore Oriti Gianni, Antonino Di Nardo Mileti Carcagnintra, Giuseppe Sirna Papa, Salvatore Artino, Vincenzo Mileti Carcavecchia Spinnato, Salvatore Parrino Tanticchia, Salvatore Fragapane Malandro, Nicolò Vinci del fu 
>   Vincenzo, Nicolò Santoro Quagliata, Michele Patroniti [...] siano rei 
>   di aver portato la strage, la devastazione ed il saccheggio nel Comune di Alcàra contro la classe di quelle persone civili, ed ai sensi della cennata rubrica dell'avvocato fiscale? 
>                         
>              
>                         
>   LA COMMISSIONE
>          Considerando [...] 
>          Per siffatte considerazioni la Commissione nella quistione proposta dichiara all'unanimità
>                         
>              
>                         
>    **COSTA**
>          [...] 
>          Risolute in tal modo le quistioni di fatto, la Commissione procedeva all'applicazione della pena, e condannò taluni all'estremo 
>   supplizio, altri a pene temporanee; però temperando la severità della 
>   legge, raccomandò alcuni fra i condannati a morte alla clemenza del Dittatore.

Si tratta di parte di un documento storico emesso dalla Commissione Speciale di Patti  nel 1860 dopo i fatti di Alcàra Li Fusi.

La mia domanda è sul significato di questo "costa" che appare un paio di volte in questo testo. Alla voce "costare" dei dizionari che ho consultato non mi sembra che si trovi niente che abbia senso in questo contesto. Potrebbe essere una forma arcaica di "constare"?

Comment: Sarà sinonimo di "constare" o "constatare"?

Comment: Sicuramente “consta”. Come “istante” viene da *instans*. Se guardi http://treccani.it/vocabolario/istante1/ vedi un altro esempio in cui la “n” cade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il gruppo consonantico “nst” del latino *instans* o *constans* nell'italiano “volgare” perde la “n” per assimilazione: *istante* e *costante*. Va notato che l'assimilazione di “ns” in “s” (sorda) era già presente nel latino classico: *mens* e *consul* si pronunciavano *mes* (da *mensem* deriva l'italiano *mese*) e *cosul* con la vocale nasalizzata. Si veda [Latin spelling and pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_spelling_and_pronunciation#Vowel_nasalization) e la citazione relativa.

Le voci dotte, entrate nel periodo umanistico e successivo, invece mantengono la “n”: “constare”. Ma non è rara l'assimilazione anche per questi lemmi, per esempio [*istante*](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/istante1/) per *instante*.

Qui il significato è [*consta*](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/constare/). Il verbo latino *constare* ha due esiti in italiano, il “volgare” *costare* e il dotto *constare*.

Comment: I am sure this is the right answer. Could you just elaborate a bit more, perhaps with some source, about the _mes_ and _consul_ pronunciation? Were those vowels nasal one, like in French?